# Well Ordering Principle proof for amount of postage

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, well-orders

I have encountered this task for WOP practicing and struggle with forming set of counterexamples and moving on from there.

> (a) Prove using the Well Ordering Principle that, using $6¢$, $14¢$, and
> $21¢$ stamps, it is possible to make any amount of postage over $50¢$. To
> save time, you may specify assume without proof that $50¢$, $51¢$, $\dots$,
> 100¢ are all makeable, but you should clearly indicate which of these
> assumptions your proof depends on.
>
> (b) Show that $49¢$ is not makeable.

So, if we assume
$$P(n) = \text {It's possible to make any amount of postage over $50¢$ using $6¢$, $14¢$, and $21¢$ stamps}\text,$$
then:
$$C = \{n \ge 50 | \neg P(n)\}$$
But how should we move on from here?

Possibly we can make something like this:
$$6k_1 + 14k_2 + 21k_3 = 50$$

Then we have to find something smaller, like $c-1$ and show that C is either empty or not and prove by contradiction. How to approach it from here?

Comment: (b) 14+14+21=49, though...

Comment: @Arthur, LOL. Didn't even notice. Actually yes)

Comment: What the problem expects you to do is to notice that, if $x>100$, then $x-50>50$ so if you can make $x-50$ you can make $x$ (by adding any coins that make up to $50$ to any coins that make up to $x-50$). Now, of course @Arthur has just shattered the whole problem, but you can still use $49$ instead ot $50$ in the above logic.

Comment: @StinkingBishop, Hmm, and we need to show that x-50 is actually smaller than x and by WOP proposition is not valid?

Comment: @Twinkle_Monkey Yep, something like that. In fact, to use WOP you look at the set of all integers $x>50$ for which the statement is not true. Suppose this set is nonempty. Take the smallest such $x$, as per WOP. Use the argument from my previous comment to derive a contradiction.